# how to integrate 1-tanh(x)

Tags: definite-integrals

I think that for solving

$\int_0^\infty 1-tanh(x)dx$

I have to use the fact that $tanh(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}$, so that the integral becomes:

$2\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}dx$

At this point I was thinking to change variable. Maybe something like $u=e^{x}+e^{-x}$ or $u=e^{-x}$. But it did not work.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Maybe try multiplying and dividing by $e^x$.

Comment: Why didn't $u=e^{-x}$ work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Use the change of variable $x \to -\ln u$. Then you have
$$-2\int \frac{1}{u} \frac{e^{\ln u}}{e^{-\ln u}+e^{\ln u}}$$
$$-2\int \frac{1}{u} \frac{u}{\frac{1}{u}+u}$$
$$-2\int \frac{u}{1+u^2}$$
I think you can figure it out from here...

Answer (score 2):

### Show

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} 1-  \tanh x \, dx = \ln 2
$$

## Solution

You are one the right track by writing the problem in exponential form.

**Substitution**

We have
$$
\tanh x = \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} 
$$
Use the substitution
$$
  \color{blue}{u = \cosh x}, \qquad \color{blue}{du = \sinh x \, dx}
$$
The integral is now
$$
 \int \tanh x \, dx = \int \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} dx 
 = \int \frac{du}{u} = \ln u
$$
The full integral is
$$
\int 1-  \tanh x \, dx = x - \ln \cosh x
$$

---

**Evaluate boundary terms**

Take the limits
$$
 \lim_{x\to \infty} \left( x - \ln \cosh x \right) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \left( x - \ln \frac{e^{x}}{2} \right) = 
\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( x - \ln e^{x} + \ln 2 \right) = \ln 2
$$
The limit $x\to 0$ is trivial. The final answer is
$$
\boxed{
\int_{0}^{\infty} 1-  \tanh x \, dx = \ln 2
}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
\int (1-\tanh x)dx = \int dx-\int \tanh x dx
$$
and
$$
\int \tanh x dx=\int \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x} dx=\ln(\cosh(x)) +C
$$
is a standard integral, easy calculated with the substitution $$ \cosh x= u \quad \rightarrow \quad du=\sinh x\, dx$$

Answer (score 1):

First I tried simplifying the integrand by multiplying and dividing by $e^x$. This gave

$2 \int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{e^{2x}+1} \ dx$.

It would be nice to use u-substitution with $u=e^x$ but it doesn't work. But notice that you can multiply and divide by $e^x$ again:

$2 \int_0^\infty \dfrac{e^x}{(e^{2x}+1)e^x} \ dx$

Now let $u=e^x$. The integral becomes

$2 \int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{(u^2+1)u} \ du$.

Then you can use partial fractions by writing $\dfrac{1}{(u^2+1)u}$ in the form $\dfrac{A}{u}+\dfrac{Bx+C}{u^2+1}$, solving for $A$ and $B$, and then integrating. The main steps can be found here: https://www.mathway.com/popular-problems/Calculus/564881